# disabling touchpad buttons at startup with command subtitution

Tags: command-line, 18.04, touchpad, xinput

I am trying to disable the right and middle mouse buttons on the touchpad and make them function as the left button.

The command that I use is this

`xinput set-button-map "11" "1" "1" "1"`

It works in my startup. However, the id keeps changing every time I restart.

So I use the following command,

`xinput set-button-map "$(xinput | grep -Po 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad\s+id=\K[0-9]+')" "1" "1" "1"`

However, it does not work, even if I delay by 30 seconds.

What can I do to make this work? Or is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

I used `xinput set-button-map "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad" "1" "1" "1"` instead.